# Why does this lead to an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

There is something that doesn't quite make sense to me. Why does this:

```
public static int[] countNumbers(String n){
int[] counts = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++){
    if (Character.isDigit(n.charAt(i)))
        counts[n.charAt(i)]++;
}
return counts;
}
```

bring up an ArrayOutOfBounds error while this:

```
  public static int[] countNumbers(String n){
    int[] counts = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isDigit(n.charAt(i)))
            counts[n.charAt(i) - '0']++;
    }
    return counts;
    }
```

does not? The only difference between the two examples is that the index for counts is being subtracted by zero in the second example. If I'm not mistake, shouldn't the first example display correctly since the same value is being checked?

Here are the value being passed for the two methods:

```
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
String phone = input.nextLine();

//Array that invokes the count letter method
int[] letters = countLetters(phone.toLowerCase());

//Array that invokes the count number method
int[] numbers = countNumbers(phone);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
 counts[n.charAt(i)]++;
```

`n.charAt(i)` is a character, which will be converted to an integer. So '0' is actually 48, for example... but your array only has 10 elements.

Note that the working version isn't subtracting 0 - it's subtracting '0', or 48 when converted to an `int`.

So basically:

```
Character          UTF-16 code unit        UTF-16 code unit - '0'
'0'                48                      0
'1'                49                      1
'2'                50                      2
'3'                51                      3
'4'                52                      4
'5'                53                      5
'6'                54                      6
'7'                55                      7
'8'                56                      8
'9'                67                      9
```

The code is still broken for non-ASCII digits though. As it can only handle ASCII digits, it would be better to make that explicit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++){
    char c = n.charAt(i);
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        counts[c - '0']++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @Steve:- Were you trying to catch a supersonic Jon Skeet! ;)

Answer (score 0):

'0' is quite different from 0. '0' is the code of the "zero" character.

Comment: Don't confuse the zero character '0' with the null character '\0' :)

Comment: @stuXnet Well right, you can interpret the wording "zero character" wrong, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

problem is in the line `counts[n.charAt(i)]`. here `n.charat(i)` may return values larger than 9;

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here is that you're thinking `'0' == 0`. This is not true. When treated as a number, `'0'` has the ASCII value for the character 0, which is 48.

Answer (score 0):

Because `n.charAt(i)` returns a character which is then boxed to a number.  In this case the character `0` is actually [ASCII value 48](http://www.asciitable.com/).

By subtracting character '0', you are subtracting the value 48 and taking the index into a range that is 0-9 because you've checked the character is a valid digit.